# Springboot Rest Template query param with special characters

Tags: spring, rest

I am calling an api through java code like this.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(myUrl);
builder.queryParam("sandwich","PB_&_J");

return restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(),HttpMethod.GET,MyObject.class);
```

The api service which has this param as

```
@GetMapping("myUrl")
MyObject myApiFunction( @RequestParam String sandwich){
    log(sandwich);
   //return something
}
```

doesn't consume this request correctly (It has '%26' in logs instead of '&' ).

But if I print *builder.toUriString()* which comes as *http://myurl?sandwich=PB_%26_J* and hit it via Postman, the api service consumes it correctly.

Whats wrong with the ***restTemplate*** code?

Answer (score 1):

`UriComponentsBuilder.toUriString()` encodes its variables.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#toUriString--

If you want your params not encoded, then build unencoded URI then pass it to RestTemplate.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#build--

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html#toUri--

for example,

```
restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET,MyObject.class);
```

You can pass un-encoded uri. but web browsers request encoded uri. So, I recommend you, after making your controller, test in real world browsers.

Comment: Uri builder built URI correctly as i said printing  builder.toUriString() and hitting it via Postman works, but the same thing through restTemplate is causing issue.
Also won't unencoded string lead to & messing with query params?

Comment: @Rorschach : were you able to fix this, any help appreciated!!!

Comment: @Hridya RestTemple was re-encoding the already encoded string, hence at the api end i was receiving %26 instead of `&` after decoding. I would recommend not using special characters at places like this. But if you want to you can create your own uri string with `&` in it instead of using uriBuilder, so that restTemplate does the encoding(only once). Sorry for delayed response

Comment: @Rorschach No worries, I have done it by using the URI builder. One of my query parameters has & as part of the value.